# Copy the content of an appxmainfest file to another using Pre-build command

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, pre-build-event, prebuild

I've been trying to get this re-build command working for a Windows 8 Project in Visual Studio 2012.

```
if "$(ConfigurationName)"==ReleaseOEM copy "$(ProjectDir)PackageOEM.appxmainfest" "$(ProjectDir)Package.appxmainfest" copy "$(ProjectDir)StoreManifestOEM.xml" "$(ProjectDir)StoreManifest.xml"
```

The xml file `StoreManifest.xml` is copied every time I do a rebuild; however the Package.appxmainfest is never changed.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked in a test project ...

```
if "$(ConfigurationName)"=="Debug" copy "$(ProjectDir)Package.appxmanifest" "$(ProjectDir)Package2.appxmainfest"
```

The only real difference is I added quotes around Debug.  It does not copy the file without the quotes. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165412%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you need to separate commands by line breaks.  Yours should probably look something like ...

```
if "$(ConfigurationName)"=="ReleaseOEM" copy "$(ProjectDir)PackageOEM.appxmainfest" "$(ProjectDir)Package.appxmainfest"
if "$(ConfigurationName)"=="ReleaseOEM" copy "$(ProjectDir)StoreManifestOEM.xml" "$(ProjectDir)StoreManifest.xml"
```